# obtaining a filled plot with matplotlib and pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Establish connection with the database
conn = sql.connect(r"C:\Users\lenovo\tradstory.db")
query = "SELECT dates,profit FROM historique"
data = pd.read_sql(query, conn,index_col="dates",parse_dates=True)
data['cumulative_profit'] = data['profit'].cumsum()
initial_balance=9500
# Supprimer la première ligne
data = data.iloc[1:]
print(data)

data["cumulative_profit"].plot(figsize=(9,6))

plt.fill_between(data.index,initial_balance, data['cumulative_profit'], alpha=0.2, color='skyblue')
plt.show()


                profit  cumulative_profit
dates                                
2023-06-03    0.00           10000.00
2023-06-03    0.00           10000.00
2023-06-03    0.41           10000.41
2023-06-03   -2.31            9998.10
2023-06-03    0.00            9998.10
...            ...                ...
2023-06-17 -443.20           12831.67
2023-06-19    0.00           12831.67
2023-06-19 -811.75           12019.92
2023-06-26    0.00           12019.92
2023-06-26    0.00           12019.92
```

this is the shape of the data frame

so basically i wanted  to plot a filled graph using pandas and matplotlib.

[image of the plot it generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKDEZ.png)

but the plot my code generates has anomalies specially for the fill_between function, the filling isn't proportionate to the plot , i've tried many things but nada. thank you inn advance for your help

Comment: Add the data to your question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Also, please show your current results and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: You haven't provided enough for me to reproduce the error. With the data you shared, I can plot the `fill_between` just fine.